# How to create LINQ Query from string?

Tags: c#, linq, string, var

I am new at LINQ and really need a help with some coding.

At the moment, I have a string and a var variables.

```
string temp = "from product in myEntities.Products where product.Name.Contains(_Name) select product";
var _Products = temp;
LvProducts.DataSource = _Products;
LvProducts.DataBind();
```

Basically, what I want to do is to be able to create a custom/complicated LINQ query by assigning it into a string beforehand. After done with composing, I assign the string into the var variable. However, this is obviously will not work. Therefore, can anyone assist me on this?

Answer (score 22):

You have a few options:

- Use the the [**Dynamic Linq**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb894665.aspx)
  libraries to construct you queries on
  the fly. The best place to get
  started is by reading [ScottGu's blog
  entry](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx). However, I don't think
  these libraries support the contains
  method in your example. [Here](http://blog.walteralmeida.com/2010/05/advanced-linq-dynamic-linq-library-add-support-for-contains-extension-.html) is
  a blog post explaining how to add
  this support.
- Directly **execute SQL** statements. Check out the MSDN docs for [Linq to Sql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399403.aspx) or [Linq to Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487208.aspx).

  ```
  var _Products = myEntities.ExecuteStoreQuery<Product>
  (@"SELECT * FROM Products WHERE [Name] In ('Item1', 'Item2')");
  ```
- Use **Linq's composable behaviour**. This might not be the most elegant solution but it works really well if you do not have too many options. You can just construct your query in multiple parts.

  ```
  var _Products = from product in myEntities.Products
                  select product

  _Products = from product in _Products 
              where product.Name.Contains(_Name)
              select product

  if FilterByPrice {
      _Products = from product in _Products 
                  where product.Price > 100 
                  select product
  }
  ```

Answer (score 8):

You can do this by compiling this Linq within some c# using the CodeDomProvider - [Adding scripting functionality to .NET applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260/adding-scripting-functionality-to-net-applications) - but this is quite heavyweight as a solution. If you want to see more about how to do this, then take a look at LinqPad - http://www.linqpad.net - the author invites you to use the decompiler to see how it works!

If the requirement is just down to simple where clauses than an alternative might be to use Dynamic Linq - see Scott Gu's posts and the sample code from Microsoft - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this can help you 
http://nlinq.codeplex.com/

BR.

Answer (score 0):

Much of the reason you use LINQ in the first place is to get compiler-verified queries, that wil ldetect errors at compile time. This will defeat that purpose since the string will be parsed at runtime.

For your needs you have two options:

1) Making a eSQL query and running it on the ObjectContext. Using this, you can still use your entities like myEntities.Products, and return a list of products.

2) Using a normal SQL query, and use the ObjectContext to call that directly towards the underlying database.

Comment: What if this is simply Linq to Objects? (Not EF, not a DB back-end)

Comment: @Serge - In that case he can still use the SQL option of course, but the eSQL option is out the window then ;)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you will have to use dynamic code execution. For further details, have a look at Ricks post on [west-wind](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/dynamicCode/DynamicCode.htm).

Answer (score -3):

you're thinking of it like a Dynamic SQL where you create the statement as string and parse it as a SQL statement.

Since you're already in the code, why not make the statements right in there. It would be a lot easier if you use Lambda instead of the traditional linq. my 2 cents.