# Is it possible to use a string for a LINQ query expression?

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I need to extract some records if some variables have some values.

For example, if status>0 I need to filter result like :

```
where object.id=status
```

else, if status=0, I need to remove this where clauses and return all elements. I'll get rid about :

```
if(status>0)
   do a linq query with the where clauses
else
   do a link query with that where clauses
```

too much code, because the variables to check could be more than 4-5.

Is it possible to "inject" a sort of string on LINQ? (So i can create my string and pass it to the LINQ).

I mean somethings like :

```
string myQuery="";
if(status>0)
   myQuery="where object.id=status";
else
   myQuery="";
```

is it possible? (Classic mysql behaviour).

Comment: This has been asked many times. Please search "dynamic LINQ".

Comment: It is possible using dynamic linq - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139467/how-to-create-linq-query-from-string/5139491#5139491

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since LINQ is lazy, you can just do

```
var query = ...

if (status > 0)
{
    query = query.Where(o => o.id == status);
}
```

Comment: Looks interessant this approch! But in fact I do 2 queries : one for extract ALL records, one filtering with this approch. Is not a waste of resources?

Comment: If you don't have many records, you can perform only one query for all records, then filter the collection in memory using LINQ to Objects

Comment: @markzzz: Only one query is run here. You can keep building the query adding `Where()` clauses; the query isn't executed until you demand the results. If you want to first get all the records and then filter locally, you can call `ToList()` to force the query to be executed.

Comment: Uhm...in fact I don't do the ToList() at all. I think it will be executed when I run it into a foreach? Hope do you see what I saying.. :)

Comment: Yep, `foreach` will force execution of the query as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can build up a query like this:

```
IEnumerable<MyEntity> results = MyEntityContext.MyEntities;
if (status > 0)
    results = results.Where(e => e.id == status);
```

Does that help?

Comment: As I said before, this means to execute 2 queries : one for extract all records, one for filter with the where clause. Not so good :(

Comment: Actually, because it's an `IEnumerable` (`IQueryable` works the same too), there is no database hit in building up the query until you call `ToArray()` or `ToList()` to use the data which will trigger a single database hit.

Comment: @markzzz:  No!  This does NOT execute two queries.  In fact, NO queries are executed here.  The query is not executed until you iterate the results by calling ToList (for example) or use a foreach.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible using Dynamic LINQ, see ScottGu's blog post:
[Dynamic LINQ (Part 1: Using the LINQ Dynamic Query Library)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this:

```
  var query = database.MyTable.Where(/* where for all records */);

  if (status > 0) {
      query = query.Where(o => o.id == status);
  }
```

Linq (to sql and EF) is smart enough to merge the where conditions and send one SQL statement to the database.

Comment: Where clause not needed at all here. Just use `database.MyTable;`

Comment: As I said before, this means to execute 2 queries : one for extract all records, one for filter with the where clause. Not so good :(

Comment: @markzzz That's not true. What and when things are executed is dependent to a degree on your particular LINQ provider, but for a competent SQL implementation (EF, Linq2Sql, NHibernate), nothing is executed at all in the above code, and when you do execute it in a later iteration only one query will be made, regardless of which branch was taken in generating the query expression itself.

Comment: If you have Visual studio ultimate, you can easily see what and when is executed, with Intellitrace. You will see that only one query is executed with the above code.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using dynamic linq - see [How to create LINQ Query from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139467/how-to-create-linq-query-from-string/5139491)

My answer there links to Scott Gu's posts and the sample code from Microsoft - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can write the following

```
IQueryable<T> query = dbContext.SomeObjectSet;

if (condition1) {
    query = query.Where(...)
}

if (condition2) {
    query = query.Where(...)
}
```

However, you you want to query all entities, you can filter in memory afterwards using LINQ to SQL

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you will need to have 2 different queries.

```
if(status > 0)
{
    var myquery = From ....
    where object.id = status
}
else
{
    var myquery = From ..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:  `query.Where(x=>(status>0? x.id==status : 1==1))`

Comment: This is slightly less optimal than just adding the Where clause in a separate branch, because even in the 1==1 case you still have the overhead of a delegate execution per-element. Likely not serious, but very easy to avoid.

Comment: In C#, we don't write `1==1`, we just write `true`.  Also, if he's using L2SQL or L2EF, the runtime probably won't know how to translate this - a better way of writing it, if you *truly* wanted to do it this way, would be `Where(x => x.id == status || status <= 0)`

Comment: @ BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft: You are right (though it works my way also); I'm used to writing `1=1` because of sql background  :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you attempting to do a conditional LINQ query? if so maybe this would help

```
var nums = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
bool getOdd = true;

var query = nums.AsQueryable();

if (getOdd) {
    query = query.Where(i => i == 1 || i == 3);
} else {
    query = query.Where(i => i == 2 || i == 4);
}

var result = query.ToList();
```