# Enabling scripts for .NET application

Tags: c#, scripting

I would like to have scripts in my .NET 3.5 C# application. I'd like to enable user to do various actions with items currently operated by UI only (e.g. search items, export them and so on).

I would like to have a dedicated window for script, to have debugging (step by step debugging, breakpoints, watches windows) and so on.

What are the best approaches for C# applications for my .NET version? Is it possible to use C# itself as a scripting language? Are there any other possibilities, third-party libraries and controls?

Comment: IronPython, IronRuby, IronScheme, F# repl, etc. - you've got a lot of options, including even implementing your own DSL, which might be a good idea and is not such a complicated task as it is normally perceived.

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Adding scripting functionality to .NET applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260/adding-scripting-functionality-to-net-applications)*.