# VB.NET script extension

Tags: .net, vb.net

This is more for advice on a direction rather than an actual issue.

What I have:

Large scale test automation / GUI written in VB.NET/XAML

Currently all the test scripts are compiled Visual Basic source (obviously not ideal.)

What I need:

Test scripts in a different language that can be run / interpreted during run-time of my program. I need this language to have some mechanism of talking to my existing code and triggering my existing GUI. I would like these to be written / configurable by and end user, so they can be kept in source. Other than that I'm pretty flexible.

I'm assuming people have done this kind of thing before for .NET and may have some interesting approaches.

I believe the posted approach has some interesting information. And I was looking at using [IronPython](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IronPython) already, I'm just concerned that the level of interaction required may complicate things. I'm also concerned about newer developments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding scripting functionality to .NET applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260/adding-scripting-functionality-to-net-applications)

Comment: Very related and somewhat similar, but most of the responses are from nearly 10 years ago. Hoping someone could provide a more updated approach.